# New Local variable inside large FOR loops, is this a issue?

Tags: javascript

In this simple example function:

```
doSomething = function(withThisId) {
  var videos      = getVideos(), // array of videos
      discovered  = false
  ;

  for(var i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
    var keepToCheck = videos[i];

    if(keepToCheck.id == withThisId) {
      discovered = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  return discovered;
};
```

I would like to know if:

1. Inside the `for` loop, we initialise a new variable called `keepToCheck` each time we iterate and then use that for something. Does this mean that a new variable is created each time, so potentially we have the possibility of 50,000 `keepToCheck` variables existing in memory (until GC clears it)?

   Or is the JS engine smart enough to know that the variable can be reused and not create duplicates?
2. Is there a performance benefit if we initialise `var keepToCheck` outside the `for` loop and then just set it as `keepToCheck = videos[i];`?

I've been trying to research this but cant find any suggestions on the net.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, only one variable will be created. After the first iteration, `keepToCheck` already exists and will be overwritten, not created anew.

However, for organisation purposes I prefer to list all variables as soon as I know they are needed. In this case, I would have:

```
var videos = getVideos(),
    discovered = false,
    keepToCheck, i;
```

Followed by the rest of the code. If some variables are only used inside an `if`, I `var` them first thing in that block.

Comment: that's false, another variable is created sending the previous one to garbage collection.

Answer (score 1):

Variables are "hoisted" to the top of the function they are declared in and get garbage collected (completely up to the VM/browser to schedule) if overwritten.  Repetitive var statements (e.g., in a loop) are just wasteful.  While there will not be 50k variables in memory, it wastes processing time and some memory depending on when garbage collection runs.  That's why it's best to declare vars at the top of the function.  Try running JSLint/JShint on this code to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know a lot about JS, but in other languages with garbage collection, the local variables are not subject to garbage collection - they live on the stack, so after the scope is left they are gone. Thus, you can't have more than one of these variables existing at the same time. However you might end up with different addresses for each iteration.

Comment: JS garbage collection is dependent on the browser, so it could run during a callstack or not.  There's really no way to tell.